# Pandas DataFrame map string path in to integer path

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a pandas `DataFrame` like Following.

```
In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                'path'  : ["abc,cde,eg,ba","abc,cde,ba","abc,yz,zx,eg","abc,cde,eg,ba","abc,cde","abc","cde,eg,ba"]})

In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
   id           path
0   1  abc,cde,eg,ba
1   2     abc,cde,ba
2   3   abc,yz,zx,eg
3   4  abc,cde,eg,ba
4   5        abc,cde
5   6            abc
6   7      cde,eg,ba
```

I want to map all these strings in path to integers.

```
abc = 1, cde = 2, eg = 3, ba = 4, yz = 5, zx = 6
```

And finally I need to get the following output.

```
    id  path
0   1  1234
1   2  124
2   3  1563
3   4  1234
4   5  12
5   6  1
6   7  234
```

Comment: what is the logic behind matching strings to numbers? how does `yz = 5, zx = 6` work?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham : There is no logic, need to map strings to unique integer value. Reason is I can not keep string values for future needs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        'path'  : ["abc,cde,eg,ba","abc,cde,ba","abc,yz,zx,eg",\
                   "abc,cde,eg,ba","abc,cde","abc","cde,eg,ba"]})
d = {'abc':'1', 'cde':'2', 'eg':'3', 'ba':'4', 'yz':'5', 'zx':'6'}
df['path'] = df['path'].apply(lambda x:int(''.join([d[i] for i in x.split(',')])))
```

Comment: Thanks, you brought me some insight :)